# How to print `[` and `,` and `]` in streams that extract from keyboard by `cin`

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++. I want to print `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end of stream when i print some string by keyboard. also it must be print `,` between each of string. notice number of strings is unknown. for example if i print in screen: `ggg hhh jj klk` the result of program must be: `[ggg,hhh,jj,klk]`. I've tried this:

```
string cur = "";

while (cin >> cur)
{
    cout << "[" << cur << ",";
}
```

but this wrong!

Edit: by @NadavS 'sanswer we have this:
[image]

by @asmmo 's answer we have this:
[image]

but my expectation is:

```
sss ddd fff ggg
[sss,ddd,fff,ggg]

ddf hjh lk iop
[ddf,hjh,lk,iop]
```

Comment: "_but this wrong!_" Wrong, how? Do you realize, that you didn't print `]` at the end of the list (`cout << ']';` after the loop)?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius , you can suppose i've write `cout << "[" << cur << "," << "]";` this is wrong too! Do you realize?

Comment: `this is wrong!`, perhaps you might tell everyone what is right, because it's certainly not obvious.

Comment: What you've stated in the pictures isn't correct. @NavdaS answer produces [this](https://godbolt.org/z/mX4XCf). Removing the space after the `,` if you don't want it shouldn't be that hard. The same demo with the space removed: https://godbolt.org/z/3byADn

Comment: See edit on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make the loop stop at some point but you didn't. So you can send an `EOF` at the end of your inputs to make it stops (using `ctrl+z` on windows and `ctrl+D` on other OSs). And to get the wanted format change your loop to

```
int main()
{

    string cur = "";
    cout << "[ ";
    if( cin >> cur) cout << cur; 
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> cur;
        if( !cin )
        {
            cout << "]" ;
            break;
         }
         cout << "," << cur;
    }


}
```

If you want to separate the inputs and outputs, you can do the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string temp{};
    while(std::cin >> temp) vec.push_back(temp);

    std::cout << "\n[ " << vec[0];
    for(int i {1}; i < vec.size(); i++) std::cout << ", " << vec[i];
    std::cout << "]";

}
```

To make `cin` stop inputting on pressing Enter, use `std::cin.peek()` which can know the next character without taking it from the stream, as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string temp{};
    while(std::cin >> temp && !(std::cin.peek() == '\n')) vec.push_back(temp);

    std::cout << "\n[" << vec[0];
    for(int i {1}; i < vec.size(); i++) std::cout << ", " << vec[i];
    std::cout << "]";

}
```

Comment: This is to thank you for devoting your time to answering my questions. your edited answer is close to my expectation. but the difference is that i want when i press `Enter` the result is printed but in your answer when i press `ctrl+z` result is printed.

Comment: @DavRay I think the last snippet is what you are looking for isn't it

Comment: thanks, yes, it is. one another question: Is it possible to not finish the program after pressing ‍Enter but the result is printed and the program to get ready for the next strings?

Comment: @DavRay the program finished because there is no other commands to execute. If you write another command after `std::cout << "]";`, it will execute.

Comment: wait !-) _some time_ last element of `vec` isn't been printed!

Answer (score 2):

I always program these loops with some code duplication. There are other solutions, but the general concept is separating the first case from the others.

```
string cur = "";
cout << '[';
if (cin >> cur) {
  cout << cur;

  while (cin >> cur) {
    cout << ',' << cur;
  }
}
cout << ']';
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3byADn)

edit: Despite the fact this solution works, the question asker views his "stdin" and "stdout" in "the same window", so the output doesn't look pretty, and the solution should be to store a list of strings from `cin` and only then start printing.

```
string cur = "";
std::vector<string> all_strings;
while (cin >> cur) {
  all_strings.push_back(cur);
}
cout << '[';
bool first = true;
for (auto& a : all_strings) {
  if (first) {
    first = false;
  } else {
    cout << ", ";
  }
  cout << a;
}
cout << ']';
```

Comment: @DavRay "_this wrong too_" - How is it wrong? It looks like it should do what you asked for.

Comment: @DavRay If an answer doesn't meet your expectations, you should be a bit clearer why is that. This answer is wrong *how*? What input did you try, what output you got and what output you expected?

Comment: @NadavS This is to thank you for devoting your time to answering my questions. your edited answer is close to my expectation. but the difference is that i want when i press `Enter` the result is printed but in your answer when i press `ctrl+z` result is printed.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports it, [`std::experimental::ostream_joiner`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner) does this.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "[";
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << "]";
}
```

[Outputs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e93ece14034a6173) `[ggg,hhh,jj,klk]` from `ggg hhh jj klk`